# Text Area for Rich Text Editing

Tags: asp.net, html

Is it possible to use Basic HTML TextArea for RichText Editing?

If not, what benefit we have out of using TextArea instead of TextBox?

I DO NOT want any third party editors. Looking for some option available by default in ASP.NET or HTML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TextBox is single line editor and TextArea is multi line editor, there is no default implementation of rich text editing in HTML so far. All third party libraries use some sort of DIV or IFRAME and enable "editing" feature and they wrap javascript code with buttons to make a good rich text editor. ASP.NET doesnt have any inbuilt rich text editor either.